# What does '.' and '..' mean in Matlab dir() command?

Tags: matlab

I'm using the dir() command in matlab to list all contents of a certain directory. The output of this command is a structure array that looks like the following:

```
'.'                     '15-Oct-2015 13:13:52'  0   true    736252.551296296
'..'                    '15-Oct-2015 13:13:52'  0   true    736252.551296296
'2015.07.28'            '16-Oct-2015 17:01:40'  0   true    736253.709490741
'2015.08.14 10-38_r'    '26-Oct-2015 10:05:45'  0   true    736263.420659722
'2015.08.14 10-41_r'    '21-Oct-2015 17:56:30'  0   true    736258.747569445
'2015.08.14 11-16_r'    '16-Oct-2015 10:16:20'  0   true    736253.428009259
'2015.08.14 11-21_r'    '16-Oct-2015 10:30:24'  0   true    736253.437777778
'2015.08.14 11-23_r'    '26-Oct-2015 10:21:22'  0   true    736263.431504630
```

Rows 3 through end make complete sense to me, but my question is, what does '.' and '..' mean? All I've found is that there is no way to remove them other than explicitly removing it from the structure array.

Removing it is not an issue, I'm just curious as to what they mean and why they are there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The same thing it means in unix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same meaning like in good old DOS.
`.` is the current directory.
`..` is the parent directory.
`cd..` for example lets you navigate into the parent dir.

Comment: `cd ..` might be more portable, at least if I remember correctly that both `cd..` and `cd ..` are valid in DOS (while in linux, only the latter).